# the weblogic service started and then stopped

Tags: windows, weblogic

I am trying to install Weblogic server as a windows service. The installation is complete and when i tried to run the service its throwing the following error.

**The XX service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.**

Below is the script that I used for installing the service.

```
REM echo off
SETLOCAL
set DOMAIN_NAME=FrDomain
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware1\user_projects\domains\FrDomain
set SERVER_NAME=AdminServer
set WL_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware1\wlserver_10.3
set ADMIN_URL=http://someUrl:7001/
set WLS_USER=weblogic
set WLS_PW=weblogic
set PRODUCTION_MODE=true
cd %USERDOMAIN_HOME%
call "%USERDOMAIN_HOME%\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd"
call "%WL_HOME%\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"
ENDLOCAL
```

I had referred forums where they advised to **clear the Event log and increase the log size**, check **“Overwrite events when needed”**, or to **try Log on as Local System Account**. Those not worked in this case. 
How to resolve the above error and start the service. Kindly help on this issue.

Comment: What is the error in the logs?

Comment: No errors were shown. It was successfully installed. Yet while starting the service, its showing the error as :'The XX service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs'

Comment: Yes but it depends on what the weblogic logs say. It could be anything by the sound of it. You need to be more specific. Try and see if it actually hit the weblogic server.

Answer (score 1):

Try below which is working for me without any issue

echo off
SETLOCAL

### call "\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd"

### -

-
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.Stdout="\stdout.out"
-Dweblogic.Stderr="\stderr.txt" %JAVA_OPTIONS%

call "\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"
ENDLOCAL

Comment: just do a "call "\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd"" after setting Domain name and add set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.Stdout="\stdout.out"
-Dweblogic.Stderr="\stderr.txt" %JAVA_OPTIONS%  --- before call "\server\bin\installSvc.cmd" for creating logs.. :)