# Weblogic Service Stops after Starting

Tags: windows, service, weblogic

I know that this question was asked, but not answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814579/the-weblogic-service-started-and-then-stopped), but my reputation isn't high enough to post a comment yet and I didn't want to post this as an Answer on that post, so please forgive me asking a duplicate question.

I'm having the exact same problem in that my Weblogic service starts and then stops shortly after.  I tried the recommendations listed in this article, but unfortunately, they did not help.  My stderr and stdout logs were created in my defined %USERDOMAIN_HOME% directory, but the logs are empty.  The Windows Event logs just show that the service started and then another entry showing that it stopped.

I did adjust the service logon options and increased my event log file size to 2048 KB.  Below is my createSvc.cmd file.  I also added a system variable for JAVA_HOME to my JDK install folder.  I would appreciate any insight.  Thank you.

```
echo off
SETLOCAL
set DOMAIN_NAME=base_domain
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain
call "%USERDOMAIN_HOME%\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd"
set SERVER_NAME=myWLSserver
set WL_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\
set ADMIN_URL=http://127.0.0.1:7001
set WLS_USER=weblogic
set WLS_PW=password
set PRODUCTION_MODE=true
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.Stdout="%USERDOMAIN_HOME%\stdout.txt" -Dweblogic.Stderr="%USERDOMAIN_HOME%\stderr.txt" %JAVA_OPTIONS%
set JAVA_VENDOR="sun"
set JAVA_VM=-server
set MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
call "%WL_HOME%\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: At least, are you able to start the server using the start script and not the windows service ? 
Can you post the server log ?

Comment: Hello, yes, I can manually start Weblogic 12c using the CMD file to start Weblogic. I am also able to login into the console. I was able to install my WAR files and my app runs okay.